# Android, Canvas and Screens

Tags: android, image, canvas, 2d, fragmentation

I think I've got quiet a common problem in regards to Android development, but cant seem to find the answer I'm looking for.

If I make a canvas on Photoshop 800x480px (240ppi) and make a logo within that canvas that is 282 x 121px, I cant understand why when I display the image it takes up 3/4 of the screen in my emulator with the same 800x480px.

The code I use to display the logo is the following

```
Bitmap logo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);

//in the onDraw
canvas.drawBitmap(logo, 0, 0, null);
```

Thanks in advance!

---

**Possible Solution**

Not sure if this is the best way to do things and would appriciate any feedback, I came across this solution (typically when you've already posted a question :D ) was to code the image as follows:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;

//Load images
logo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo, options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image was probably only taking up 3/4 of the screen in the emulator because of the pre-scaling android sometimes does.

Check out [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) on how to handle multiple resolutions and screen sizes.

You could try placing the drawable into a 'res/drawable-mdpi/' directory or a 'res/drawable-ldpi/' to differentiate between medium density and low density screens. Another option is to place it in a 'res/drawable-nodpi/' directory to prevent any pre-scaling. I've even placed some images in the 'res/raw' folder to get the same effect.

However, if your current method works, go for it!

Comment: yea thats what I thought, but it seemed to do the trick (above solution) stranger than fiction :)